# unable to print variable value inside angular function

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I have written the following code but this code doesn't seems to be working for me.

html:

```
<form class= "ui large form segment">
  <h3 class= "ui header">Add a link</h3>

  <div class="field">
    <label for = "title">Title: </label>
    <input name= "title" #newtitle>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for = "link">Link: </label>
    <input name= "link" #newlink>
  </div>

<button (click) = "addArticle(newtitle, newlink)" class= "ui positive right floated button">
  Submit link
</button>

</form>
```

.ts

```
addArticle(title : HTMLInputElement, link : HTMLInputElement):boolean{
    console.log('Adding article with title: ${title.value} and link ${link.value}');
    return false;
  }
```

when I run the code I get below output in the console, don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
Adding article with title: ${title.value} and link ${link.value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Single Quote(') instead of backtick(`), try the below code, it should work

```
addArticle(title : HTMLInputElement, link : HTMLInputElement):boolean{
    console.log(`Adding article with title: ${title.value} and link ${link.value}`);
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Replace single quotes with backtick